# How to configure proxypass and proxyreverse pass in apache tomcat server 8.0?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I know that httpd is a web server and it will not be included with tomcat 8.0, but from the documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html, Apache tomcat now supports to configure proxypass and proxyreversepass.

I recently installed Apache tomcat for the latest version, but still not able to find the httpd.conf file, but how the information in above link is valid if we still did not get httpd.conf file with latest version?

Comment: You completely misunderstand what you're reading in this doc. There are 2 different products, Apache which will be the reverse-proxy, and Tomcat which will be the application server. Always like that everywhere.

Comment: Sorry I am new to tomcat environment, could you let me know how to enable httpd in tomcat to use those proxypass and proxyreversepass?

Comment: No, proxypass/proxypassreverse are in httpd.conf which is related to Apache. Tomcat (known as Apache Tomcat) is another software.

Answer (score 0):

Install Xampp and you can find the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).